# Предупреждение о включении геолокации

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Подскажите, создал приложение оно запрашивает разрешение на местоположение пользователя (добавил в info.plist строки

`

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>The spirit of stack overflow is coders helping coders</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>I have learned more on stack overflow than anything else</string>
```

` )

Теперь, когда юзер сворачивает приложение вверху экрана остаётся предупреждение о том что моё приложение использует геолокацию, Как избавиться от этого предупреждения?
**UPDATE**

```
    self.myLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[self.myLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"####"];
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:59.93 longitude:30.35 zoom:9];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = true;
//  mapView_.showsUserLocation = YES;
//mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
mapView_.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
mapView_.center = self.view.center;
[self.scrollView addSubview:mapView_];
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы приложение не использовало геолокацию в бэкграунде, надо оставить только один ключик - NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

**UPDATE**

Немного инструкций по активации локейшен манагера

```
- (void)setupLocationService
{
    // проверить, включен ли локейшен сервис на телефоне.
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;

        // проверить авторизацию
        CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
        if(authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
        {
            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
        else
        {
            // если все ок, то запускаем определение места
            [self runUpdatingLocation];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Алерт с просьбой включить сервис в настройках
    }
}

- (void)runUpdatingLocation
{
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

// обработать коллбэки делегата
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    if((self.authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) || (self.authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse))
    {
        [self runUpdatingLocation]
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
  self.currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
}
```

Comment: все равно выводится предупреждение

Comment: Как запрашивается авторизация пользователя?
1. Надо вызывать [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] вместо requestAlwaysAuthorization
2. Для проверки сбросить настройки – Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy

Comment: В вопросе выложил код

Comment: Обновил свой пост

Comment: Я тут вспомнил, что если при сворачивании приложения не остановить обновление позиции принудительно, то приложение (а значит и обновление) будет активно в фоновом режиме еще некоторое время - 30 сек. Проверьте и эту возможность

Comment: ваш код просто вставить в мою view? И приложение не будет работать в бэграунде?

Comment: Нет, просто вставить не получится. Как минимум - надо завести во вьюшке проперти для locationManager :)

Comment: я изменил locationManager на myLocationManager (как в моём коде) и для authorizationStatus задал пропети NSString из-за этого может не работать? и для currentLocation какое нужно задать пропети?

Comment: property (nonatomic, assign) CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus;
property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;

Comment: не работает...нашёл такую штуку     `if(&UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification) { //needed to run on older devices, otherwise you'll get EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(enteredForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
    }` она оставляет бар, но при нажатии на предупреждение сворачивает его